# How to make Eclipse detect the right Java source code

Tags: eclipse

When trying to jump to Java API source code (by Ctrl/Cmd+Click) it shows `Source not found` and has an option to `Attach source...`

I'm a mac user, I installed only JDK, and eclipse can find the Java API source code without me setting anything. But for Windows/Ubuntu, even I install only the JDK, it always ask to `Attach source...` in the first time. Which I'm tired of telling every single one of my friends how to fix this, because there are so many steps.

So I don't know if I installed Eclipse & JDK (on Windows/Ubuntu) wrongly, or this is normal. And are there any way to install Eclipse and JDK so it could use Ctrl+Click to jump to a readable source code right on the first time?

Note: The JDK is downloaded from `oracle.com` (Windows), `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` (Ubuntu). And Eclipse is downloaded as `zip` from `eclipse.org` (not the Eclipse Installer because I needed to share through USB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Eclipse Java IDE the default JRE is set to the JRE that is used to run Eclipse. In Windows, when installing a JDK, a JRE is also installed (e. g. after installing a 64 bit JDK you will have both `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<version>\bin\java.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jre<version>\bin\java.exe`). Unfortunately, the JRE is used by Windows by default and therefore by Eclipse by default.

In your case, maybe the easiest way is to **add an embedded Java JDK to your Eclipse ZIP** to share (this **also avoids the need to install Java**):

1. **Create a folder `jre`**
2. **Copy** everything from a **Java JDK** installation directory (e. g. installed Windows 64 bit Java JDK: from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9`) into the `jre` folder
3. **Add the `jre` folder to your Eclipse ZIP to share**